# Access to type being resolved at install time with windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have a large number of classes depending on a watchdog component. I add a reference to the depending class to the watchdog instance.

Currently I use the following code to accomplish this.

```
   class MyClass {
      public MyClass(IWatchDog watchDog) {
        watchDog.WatchingType = typeof(MyClass);
      }
   }
```

My installer:

```
class IoC: IWindsorInstaller {
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) {
        container.Register(Component.For<MyClass>());
        container.Register(Component.For<IWatchDog>().ImplementedBy<WatchDogService>());
    }
}
```

Is it possible to let the installer do this assignment for me? Here's what I have in mind in pseudo-code, OnResolving being my imaginary method:

```
class IoC : IWindsorInstaller {
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) {
        container.Register(Component.For<MyClass>());
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IWatchDog>()
                .ImplementedBy<WatchDogService>()
                .OnResolving<IWatchDog>(
                    new Action((Type typeBeingResolved, IWatchDog instance) =>
                        instance.WatchingType = typeBeingResolved));

    }
}
```

So in this case I imagine `typeBeingResolved` would equal to `typeof(MyClass)` if `container.Resolve<MyClass>()` is called, or `null` if someone calls `container.Resolve<IWatchDog>()`.

Obviously, if I could somehow have access to the instance of the type being resolved a bit like in `OnCreate()` that would work as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a custom facility you can change your default activator for your components to be an activator that does what you want.  Here's a working solution:

```
using Castle.Core;
using Castle.MicroKernel;
using Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Context;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Facilities;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks; 

namespace ComponentCreater
{
public interface IWatchDogService
{
    Type WatchingType { get; set; }
}

public class WatchDogService : IWatchDogService
{
    public Type WatchingType { get; set; }
}


public class WatchedClassViaConstructor
{
    private readonly IWatchDogService watchDogService;

    public WatchedClassViaConstructor(IWatchDogService watchDogService)
    {
        this.watchDogService = watchDogService;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.watchDogService.WatchingType.Name);
    }
}

public class WatchDogFacility : AbstractFacility
{
    protected override void Init()
    {
        this.Kernel.ComponentModelCreated += Kernel_ComponentModelCreated;
    }

    private void Kernel_ComponentModelCreated(ComponentModel model)
    {
        model.CustomComponentActivator = typeof(WatchedComponentActivator);   
    }
}

public class WatchedComponentActivator : DefaultComponentActivator
{
    public WatchedComponentActivator(ComponentModel model, IKernel kernel, ComponentInstanceDelegate onCreation, ComponentInstanceDelegate onDestruction)
        : base(model, kernel, onCreation, onDestruction)
    {
    }

    protected override object CreateInstance(CreationContext context, ConstructorCandidate constructor, object[] arguments)
    {
        object component = base.CreateInstance(context, constructor, arguments);

        if (arguments != null)
        {
            IWatchDogService watchDogService = arguments.FirstOrDefault(arg => arg is IWatchDogService) as IWatchDogService;
            if (watchDogService != null)
            {
                watchDogService.WatchingType = component.GetType();
            }
        }

        return component;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<WatchDogFacility>();

        container.Register(
            Component.For<IWatchDogService>()
                .ImplementedBy<WatchDogService>()
                .LifestyleTransient(),
            Component.For<WatchedClassViaConstructor>()
        );

        WatchedClassViaConstructor obj = container.Resolve<WatchedClassViaConstructor>();
        obj.Print();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

If you're into AOP and like to have your classes remain clutter free, you can use a slightly modified version of the above that lets your watched classes look like this:

```
public class WatchedClassViaInheritance : WatchedClass
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.WatchDogService.WatchingType.Name);
    }
}
```

This uses the same tactics, but uses property injection.  I've created a component model construction contributor to enforce castle to require IWatchDogServcie to be injected much like you'd be required to do if it was constructor injection.  Here's the code for that:

```
namespace ComponentCreater2
{
using Castle.Core;
using Castle.MicroKernel;
using Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Context;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Facilities;
using Castle.MicroKernel.ModelBuilder;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public interface IWatchDogService
{
    Type WatchingType { get; set; }
}

public class WatchDogService : IWatchDogService
{
    public Type WatchingType { get; set; }
}

public interface IIsWatched
{
    IWatchDogService WatchDogService { get; set; }
}

public abstract class WatchedClass : IIsWatched
{
    public IWatchDogService WatchDogService { get; set; }
}

public class WatchedClassViaInheritance : WatchedClass
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.WatchDogService.WatchingType.Name);
    }
}

public class WatchDogFacility : AbstractFacility
{
    protected override void Init()
    {
        this.Kernel.ComponentModelCreated += Kernel_ComponentModelCreated;
        this.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.AddContributor(new RequireWatchDogService());
    }

    private void Kernel_ComponentModelCreated(ComponentModel model)
    {
        if (typeof(IIsWatched).IsAssignableFrom(model.Implementation))
        {
            model.CustomComponentActivator = typeof(WatchedComponentActivator);
        }
    }
}

public class WatchedComponentActivator : DefaultComponentActivator
{
    public WatchedComponentActivator(ComponentModel model, IKernel kernel, ComponentInstanceDelegate onCreation, ComponentInstanceDelegate onDestruction)
        : base(model, kernel, onCreation, onDestruction)
    {
    }
    protected override void SetUpProperties(object instance, CreationContext context)
    {
        base.SetUpProperties(instance, context);

        IIsWatched watched = instance as IIsWatched;

        if (watched != null)
        {
            watched.WatchDogService.WatchingType = instance.GetType();
        }
    }
}

public class RequireWatchDogService : IContributeComponentModelConstruction
{
   public void ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model) 
   { 
       model.Properties.Where(prop => prop.Dependency.TargetType == typeof(IWatchDogService))
           .All(prop => prop.Dependency.IsOptional = false); 
   } 
}


class Program2
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<WatchDogFacility>();

        container.Register(
            Component.For<IWatchDogService>()
                .ImplementedBy<WatchDogService>()
                .LifestyleTransient(),
            Component.For<WatchedClassViaInheritance>()
        );

        WatchedClassViaInheritance obj = container.Resolve<WatchedClassViaInheritance>();
        obj.Print();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Trying to understand how facilities work... Your WatchDog facility seems to push forward the WatchedComponentActivator regardless of the component type. Would this play nicely with other facilities? What if I registered the TypedFactoryFacility at the same time?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work or not.  The OP didn't have a common base class or interface to do the appropriate selection, so I couldn't do much about it.  With the second example above I took the liberty of having a common interface which allowed my facility to be more selective about what components it provides a custom activator for.

Comment: I took the first example and tested creating WatchClassViaConstructor using a typed factory and it worked fine.